# Sanic - path type of endpoint doesn't include query arguments

Tags: python, routes, sanic

If I have defined my route as (*only relevant part of code*):

```
...
@app.get("brawlstats/endpoint:path>")
...
```

and I try to access route `/brawlstats/rankings/global/brawlers/16000001?limit=200`, it cuts off at the question mark. I want endpoint to include the entire url. How do I make it include the whole path ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everything after `?` is considered as part of [query string](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string). Your `endpoint` represents *path* after `/brawlstats`.

Since `endpoint` and `limit` argument are split apart, you can retrieve both with this example:

```
from sanic import Sanic
from sanic.response import text

app = Sanic()


@app.get('/brawlstats/<endpoint:path>')
async def brawlstats(request, endpoint):

    # endpoint is set to part after '/brawlstats'.
    # limit query arg is converted to integer or 0 if it's not set.
    limit = int(request.args.get('limit', 0))

    if endpoint == 'rankings/global/brawlers/16000001' and limit > 0:
        return text('Success', 200)

    return text('Bad request', 400)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host="127.0.0.1", port=8000)
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked! I realize how stupid I was when asking this question...

Comment: It wasn't stupid. It's a new framework and if you are beginner, chances are you have missed something. Please consider accepting my answer if it helped you. Thank you